# Hide ProgressChanged event

Tags: c#, events, backgroundworker

Is it possible to hide the ProgressChanged event in a backgroundworker class?

I have created a class that inherits `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` and I need to have multiple events: My class processes a list of objects and I need (for example) to have events before and after an object is processed. I fire those events from the Backgroundworker's ProgressChanged event, because it is thread safe. The method in my class that is called when I invoke `ReportProgress` then uses the parameter to determine which event to fire. That works.

Now I want to make sure, that the class **calling** my Backgroundworker is **not** allowed to subscribe to the `ProgressChanged` event directly. Instead it should only be possible to subscribe to the additional events that I provide.

Comment: C# uses the *private* keyword for that.  Encapsulate the BGW in your class and make the instance variable private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches:

**Disallow subscription and suppress firing**

The subclass can be written to (a) throw an exception if a caller attempts to subscribe directly to the `ProcessChange` event, and (b) not raise the event at all.  Note that (a) alone does not prevent the event from being subscribed to, since callers can cast the subclass as a `BackgroundWorker` and subscribe to the event directly:

```
class ExtendedBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    public new event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanges
    {
        add { throw new InvalidOperationException("This event cannot be added directly"); }
        remove {}
    }

    protected override void OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do not call base.OnProgressChanged
    }
}
```

**Use composition in place of inheritance**

If possible, however, a better approach may be to not inherit from `BackgroundWorker` at all.  A `BackgroundWorker` uses the `ProgressChanged` event to report progress changes; if it does not do so, it is not a `BackgroundWorker`.  Instead, consider implementing the BackgroundWorker as a private class member and exposing members from the member as needed, e.g.:

```
class CustomBackgroundWorker : Component
{
    private BackgroundWorker worker;
    public event ProgressChangedEventHandler FirstEvent;
    public event ProgressChangedEventHandler SecondEvent;
    public event DoWorkEventHandler DoWork
    {
        add { worker.DoWork += value; }
        remove { worker.DoWork -= value; }
    }
    public event RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler RunWorkerCompleted
    {
        add { worker.RunWorkerCompleted += value; }
        remove { worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= value; }
    }

    public CustomBackgroundWorker()
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.ProgressChanged += OnProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    public void RunWorkerAsync()
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        worker.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnProgressChanged(object o, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // code to handle progress change reports from the worker
    }
}
```

**Refire event to be of use to client**

Rather than suppressing use of the event, the subclass can use it in conjunction with (rather than as a substitute for) the other events to provide relevant information to the subscriber (e.g., the progress of the total operation).

Comment: "if it does not do so, it is not a BackgroundWorker". Good point, I was looking for a quick win, but having a clean structure is definitely preferably.